# AngularJS orderby filter by a check box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I want to use `angularJS` **orderby filter** with a checkbox as well as ordering by the column. This works fine for me :

```
<tr ng-repeat="player in players | orderBy:'id':true | rangeFilter:min:max">
  <td>{{player.id}}</td>
</tr>
```

I want to determine for `orderby` with a checkbox. How should I do that?

```
<input type="checkbox"> Order by id
```

Comment: start with giving your checkbox an `ng-model` and then using that model variable in the `orderBy` comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be help you.

```js
var myapp = angular.module('app', []);
myapp.controller('Main', function ($scope) {
  $scope.model = false;
  $scope.data =[
       {
         "content" : "some content0",
         "createdAt" : "1459401001460",
         "completed" : false
       },
      {
         "content" : "some content1",
         "createdAt" : "1459401001325",
         "completed" : true
       },
       {
         "content" : "some content2",
         "createdAt" : "1459401001460",
         "completed" : false
       },
      {
         "content" : "some content3",
         "createdAt" : "1459401001325",
         "completed" : true
       },
       {
         "content" : "some content4",
         "createdAt" : "1459401001460",
         "completed" : false
       },
      {
         "content" : "some content5",
         "createdAt" : "1459401001325",
         "completed" : true
       }
 ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app = "app">
  <div ng-controller="Main">
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="model">
<div >
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr ng-repeat="d in data | filter: {completed: model }">
            <td>{{d.content}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
   </div>
</div>
```